# How to adjust the request queue timeout in IIS

Tags: http, iis, timeout

1. Is there a time out for a http request which is kept in the IIS request queue?
2. If there is a time out, what will happens if a request stayed longer time in the IIS request queue ?

   2. a - Does it discards or execute by the server when threads available?

Comment: http://blog.leansentry.com/all-about-iis-asp-net-request-queues/

Comment: I went through the document, Unfortunately didn't find any details related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Good question, I'm surprised it's infinite by default, as a surge would overload IIS with requests (up to the limit, which is 3000 by default).

If you have a well tuned application, I would say 1-3 seconds is a good range. Users typically don't wait longer than a second anyway, they'll hit refresh. In my case I have a dinosaur with all kinds of clunky reports so have set to 30 seconds.